# DRF not catch django signal exception

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model of IP addresses in django, but this model is fed by another one where the networks are stored, for example, if I add the network `10.0.0.0/24` with a signal I populate the IP addresses table from `10.0.0.1` to `10.0.0.255`, for a validation issue I raise some exceptions in the signals and it works fine when I try to save with the shell, but when I use DRF I get an `error 500` instead of the validationError.

Does anyone know how I can make DRF return a `BAD_REQUEST` with my validationError message instead of return `HTTP_500`?